# trigger updating same table

Tags: postgresql

I have an inventory_movements table, and every time a sale is done, a new row is saved through a trigger (called "regularizestockmov").

If you delete or update a row that is not the last row, it has to update the newer (more recent) rows. I have figured out the function, but if I delete / edit a very old row, the code goes into an infinite loop.

I suppose this is because I update the same table that has the trigger and thousands of calls are done, but I don't know if should try to solve this better through PHP (the main language of the application) or keep trying within Postgres.

I pasted my trigger below, as well as the "regularizestockmov" function. You can also view the code [here](https://dpaste.org/vikY).

```
CREATE TRIGGER "regularize_stock" BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON ."inventory_movements"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ."regularizestockmov"();

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION regularizestockmov()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
declare

linea record;
current_stock decimal;
last_stock decimal;
units integer;
units_after integer;
article record;
quanti integer;
    begin



        if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then

            select * into article from articles where id = new.article_id;

            last_stock = new.quantity_after;

            FOR linea IN (
                select * from inventory_movements where company_id = new.company_id 
                and article_id = new.article_id and created_at > new.created_at order by created_at ASC
            )
            loop

                current_stock = last_stock;
                units = linea.quantity;

                update inventory_movements set quantity_before = current_stock,
                        quantity_after = (case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) then current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end) where id = linea.id;

                last_stock = (case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) then current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end);

            END LOOP;

            update articles set stock = article.stock - new.quantity where id = new.article_id;

            return new;

        elseif (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then

            new.updated_at = now()::timestamp(0);
            last_stock = case when new.io = 'E' or (new.io = 'R' and new.quantity > 0) then new.quantity_before + new.quantity else new.quantity_before - new.quantity end;

        --raise exception '% %', last_stock, new.created_at;

            FOR linea IN (
                select * from inventory_movements where company_id = new.company_id 
                and article_id = new.article_id and created_at > new.created_at order by created_at ASC
            )
            loop

                current_stock = last_stock;
                units = linea.quantity;

                update inventory_movements set quantity_before = current_stock,
                        quantity_after = (case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) then current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end) where id = linea.id;

                last_stock = case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) then current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end;
                --last_stock = current_stock - linea.quantity;

                                update migration.stock set quant = quant + 1 where art_cod = new.article_code;

            END LOOP;   

            update articles set stock = last_stock where id = new.article_id;

        return new;

        else --delete

            current_stock = old.quantity_before;

            FOR linea IN (
                select * from inventory_movements where company_id = old.company_id 
                and article_id = old.article_id and created_at > old.created_at order by created_at ASC
            )
            loop

                units = linea.quantity;

                execute 'update inventory_movements set quantity_before = $1,
                    quantity_after = $2 where id = $3;'
                    using current_stock, 
                    (case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) then current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end),
                    linea.id;

                current_stock = (case when linea.io = 'E' or (linea.io = 'R' and linea.quantity > 0) THEN current_stock + linea.quantity else current_stock - linea.quantity end);

                        update migration.stock set quant = quant + 1 where art_cod = old.article_code;


            END LOOP;

            select * into article from articles where id = old.article_id;
            last_stock = (case when old.io = 'E' or (old.io = 'R' and old.quantity > 0) then article.stock - old.quantity else article.stock + old.quantity end);       

            update articles set stock = current_stock where id = old.article_id;

            return old;

        end if;

 return null;

    END;
$function$
;
```

Any help is welcomed! and YES.. I know this can be done better, I'm not professional! thanks

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: Your code has order n-squared complexity.  if you wait long enough it should complete.